# Bash Script: Perform certain actions on files of certain extension inside a certain directory?

Tags: bash, shell, console, terminal

How do I write a Bash script that, will select all files inside `~/test` with a `.css` extension, so I can pipe them one by one into further actions?

Comment: My bash-fu is weak, and I can't test it out atm. But off the top of my head `find ~/test/*.css -type f -exec command;` *might* work. just replace `command` with your appropriate command. `-exec` runs `command` on selected output files. Alternatively, you can utilise `xargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ~/test/*.css
do
# your command 'cmd'
   cmd "$f"
done
```

To process a command for every `.css` files in one line, try like this:

```
find ~/test -type f -name '*.css' -execdir cmd {} \+
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I would like to go recursively into all subdirs of ~/test/ ?